# Leader election for paxos-based replicated key value store

Tags: distributed-system, key-value-store, paxos

I am going to implement a key value store with multi Paxos. I would have several nodes, one of which is the primary node. This primary node receive update requests and replicate values to slave nodes.

My question is how the primary node (or leader) is selected? Can I still use the Paxos algorithm? If so, do you think it is necessary to abstract the paxos implementation to a single unit that could be used not only by the replication unit but also the leader election unit？

If I use the node with the least id to be the leader? How can I implement the master lease?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this on your own? There are implementations available that do what you want and a whole bunch more, they are tested and proven in production environments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before I get to the actual question, I would suggest that for a paxos-like system, you don't think of it as a master-slave relationship, but rather an equal-peer relationship. Basic Paxos doesn't even have a leader concept. Multi-paxos tacks on a leader as a performance optimization, electing that leader is part of the protocol.

Multi-Paxos boils down to Paxos underneath: there is a prepare phase and an accept phase. The insight of Multi-Paxos is that once a node wins an accept round, it has simultaneously won leader election and after that the prepare phase isn't necessary from that leader until it detects that another node has taken over leadership.

---

And now some practical advise. I have many years of experience working on several paxos, multi-paxos, and other consensus systems.

I first suggest *not* implementing either Paxos or Multi-paxos. Optimizing Paxos systems for performance while keeping it correct is very hard—especially if you are having these types of questions. I would instead **look into implementing the Raft protocol**.

Taking both protocols as is right off the paper, the Raft protocol can have much better throughput than Multi-Paxos. The Raft authors (and others) suggest that Raft is easier to understand, and implement.

You may also look into using one of the open-source Raft systems. I don't have experience with any of them to tell you how easy it is to maintain. I have heard, though, of pain in maintaining Zookeeper instances. (I have also heard complaints about Zookeeper's correctness proof.)

Next, it has been proven that every consensus protocol can loop forever. Build into your system a time-out mechanism, and randomized backoffs where appropriate. This is how practical engineers get around theoretical impossibilities.

Finally, examine your throughput needs. If your throughput is high enough, you will need to figure out how to partition across several consensus-clusters. And that's a whole 'nother ball of wax.

Comment: I didn't know what the Raft protocol was, so I had to look it up. "Raft is a consensus algorithm that is designed to be easy to understand. It's equivalent to Paxos in fault-tolerance and performance. The difference is that it's decomposed into relatively independent subproblems, and it cleanly addresses all major pieces needed for practical systems." https://raftconsensus.github.io/

Comment: @michael where is the information source of "every consensus protocol can loop forever"?

Comment: @PatrickChan this was famously proven by Fischer, Lynch, and Patterson. It  is often called the FLP impossibility result.

Comment: @michael　thanks. The [Impossibility of Distributed Consensus with One Faulty Process](http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/arvind/cs425/doc/fischer.pdf) paper describing the FLP impossibility result wasn't proved all the theorems right in the paper.  I commented why the theorems were not proved right at the comments of rystsov's answer at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383101/theoretical-results-of-consensus-protocol-in-primary-backup-distributed-system).

Comment: @PatrickChan I agree with rystov's comment that the discussion should go to cs.stackexchange.com. It definitely shouldn't be a battle in the comments of two separate answers.

Comment: @michael thanks for the replies.  It definitely shouldn't be a battle in the comments of two separate answers.  It was nice to get help from you.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a parallel multi-paxos instance to manage the configuration of your cluster. Consider a replicated JSON object that's updated via multi-paxos contains the following information:

- Serial number
- Current leader ID
- Timestamp of current leader's lease expiration
- List of peer ids

You can use a stock paxos implementation and put all of the necessary logic in your networking layer:

- Drop all Prepare and Accept messages received from any node other than the leader until the lease expires.
- Proactively bump the serial number and your leader's lease time shortly before lease expiry.